# How to set ActiveMQ CMS producer frequency

Tags: activemq-classic, activemq-cpp

I have a CMS producer which sends message in a while loop. This is extremely fast and unnecessary. I would like to restrict this to 1 message per second or so.

```
BytesMessage *message = session->createBytesMessage();
message->setStringProperty("M_P_C_N","someMsg");
message->setStringProperty("M_P_T_N","someTopic");
message->writeBytes(data);
producer->send(message);
```

I was wondering if CMS has a function or a way to set the frequency of the sending?

Comment: Slow the producer down? This is not a problem from ActiveMQ, but a problem from the one using activeMQ.

Comment: What do you mean by "slow the producer down"? I don't want to introduce a sleep or such a hack, I am asking whether there is a facility for such purposes in the library. Plus, this example I took from the official website of ActiveMQ. It is not my production, for your information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such facility in ActiveMQ-CPP.  Controlling producer send rate is something your application needs to handle, the C++ client is only responsible for sending the messages, you are responsible for the logic surrounding what and when a message is sent.

Comment: Okay, one has to user a timer then. Thanks.